# Hummingbot - Spot vs Margin Order

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, hft

How in hummingbot can I differentiate between placing a spot order and a margin order? I've looked through the sample scripts and source code but didn't find any option to set a desired leverage (or even turn it on).

Such option is available for derivative connectors but if I understand correctly it should be used to trade futures which is not what I want.

If there is such option, would one be able to present a short code snippet showing explicitly how to place spot vs margin order?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find any answer?